# OpenCL compile failed aparapi

Tags: java, opencl, gpgpu, aparapi

Does anyone know what this means and how this could've happened? It looks right to me. I'm trying to use the GPU for a neural network.

This is the error:

```
!!!!!!! clCreateCommandQueue() failed out of host memory
May 28, 2018 6:36:39 PM com.aparapi.internal.kernel.KernelRunner fallBackToNextDevice
WARNING: Device failed for Util$1, devices={AMD<GPU>|AMD<CPU>|Java Alternative Algorithm|Java Thread Pool}: OpenCL compile failed
com.aparapi.internal.exception.AparapiException: OpenCL compile failed
    at com.aparapi.internal.kernel.KernelRunner.fallBackToNextDevice(KernelRunner.java:1286)
    at com.aparapi.internal.kernel.KernelRunner.executeInternalInner(KernelRunner.java:1550)
    at com.aparapi.internal.kernel.KernelRunner.executeInternalOuter(KernelRunner.java:1351)
    at com.aparapi.internal.kernel.KernelRunner.execute(KernelRunner.java:1342)
    at com.aparapi.Kernel.execute(Kernel.java:2856)
    at com.aparapi.Kernel.execute(Kernel.java:2813)
    at com.aparapi.Kernel.execute(Kernel.java:2753)
    at Util.Util.dotProduct(Util.java:46)
    at Network.FullyConnectedNetwork.predictOutput(FullyConnectedNetwork.java:181)
    at Network.FullyConnectedNetwork.test(FullyConnectedNetwork.java:321)
    at Run.RunFullyConnected.main(RunFullyConnected.java:32)
```

This is the code that caused the error:

```
public static double dotProduct(ArrayList<Double> in1, ArrayList<Double> in2) {

        final double[] in1Copy = new double[in1.size()];
        final double[] in2Copy = new double[in1.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < in1.size(); i++) {
            in1Copy[i] = in1.get(i);
            in2Copy[i] = in2.get(i);
        }

        final double[] result = new double[1];

        Kernel kernel = new Kernel() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = getGlobalId();
                result[0] += in1Copy[i] + in2Copy[i];
            }
        };

        Range range = Range.create(in1Copy.length);
        kernel.execute(range);
        return result[0];

    }
```

Comment: I left an answer below, but if you can tell me in the comments your system, its memory and the GPU your using I can give you a better idea of why it may have failed. Most likely you just dont have enough memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issues all lie on this line:

```
result[0] += in1Copy[i] + in2Copy[i];
```

The biggest issue here is your trying to perform a read/write operation to the same memory location (read variable) from multiple threads at the same time. Even if this was allowed it would result in unexpected results. You are working in a GPGPU environment where you want to minimize the need for locking. This means you need to use a map-reduce type approach to solve these sorts of problems. For that you should create an actual result array of the same size as in1 and in2. Perform addition into that array per thread (the map step), then as a second step add all the elements of the array together (the reduce step).

As a side note the exception your getting is unrelated to what I just mentioned. The issue is most likely that you are running on a system that simply doesnt have enough memory. For example the following runs just fine on my machine except for the issue i mentioned in the last paragraph (just tested it).

```
import com.aparapi.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DotProductTest {
  @Test
  public void dotProduct() {

        final double[] in1Copy = new double[4096];
        final double[] in2Copy = new double[4096];
        for(int i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
            in1Copy[i] = i;
            in2Copy[i] = i*10.0;
        }

        final double[] result = new double[1];

        Kernel kernel = new Kernel() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = getGlobalId();
                result[0] += in1Copy[i] + in2Copy[i];
            }
        };

        Range range = Range.create(in1Copy.length);
        kernel.execute(range);
        System.out.println(result[0]);

    }
}
```

Comment: I have enough memory when I run it without using Aparapi. The dot product is between vectors of size around 2300. I'm using Windows 10 with 8 GB RAM and Radeon RX 560 graphics card. Is the memory problem a GPU memory problem or RAM memory problem? By the way thanks for answering.

Comment: @dandan what version of aparapi you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.8.0.

Comment: @dandan it may be worth giving a try to 1.10.0 we just fixed some stuff that might be relevant here.

Comment: 1.10.0 wasn't working for me so I used 1.9.0. It doesn't appear to be released yet on maven?

Comment: @dandan 1.10.0 is a snapshot right now, not released yet.

Comment: @dandan you can reduce on the GPU if youd like. There are many ways to write a reduce function. The easiest way is to have a single thread just add everything up, in which case the CPU makes more sense for that. But you can multithread it by reducing the array by half each time and running it until the array is down to one element. This works well on the GPu.

Comment: @dandan thanks for approving my answer. I'm curious did 1.9.0 or 1.10.0 solve your problem then?

Comment: It didn't but I appreciate your help still. It could answer the question for others.

Comment: @dandan come on in to our gitter chat room. Myself or one of the other devs can help you more in depth there. https://gitter.im/Syncleus/aparapi